# Are there tools to deploy Windows-based applications besides ClickOnce?

Tags: .net, deployment

Are there tools to deploy Windows-based applications (.NET) besides ClickOnce?

Comment: Looks like question to system administrators ( http://serverfault.com )...

Answer (score 0):

VS2012 ships with [InstallShield LE](http://learn.flexerasoftware.com/content/IS-EVAL-InstallShield-Limited-Edition-Visual-Studio), which I've found to be pretty straightforward.